# Controller And Dbcontext Dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am handling unhandled exceptions with a global exception handler. When an unhandled exception occurs during the processing of the request, is the dispose method of the controller called? (Both in MVC and Web API?)

For example, I am trying to use the same EF dbcontext throughout the request. Is it safe to use this base class:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        Database = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    protected DatabaseContext Database { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Database.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

}

Comment: If you have complex lifecycles and need to thread a `DbContext` you should check out https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope its extremely powerful and rather lightweight but complex so you need a use case. That said, just reading the background that lead to the development of the lib is enlightening wrt this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but.. I am uncertain wether or not dispose is guaranteed to run in all edge cases. BUT it should be easy for you to test your scenario.

With that said is appears that it is not actually critical to dispose your dbcontext at all. AAs principle it should be done as good practise. But,as pointed out in Jon Gallants blog post [here](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/), it is not necessary according to MS devs. Therefor it will most likely not matter at all IF, in some rare occasions, your dbcontext were not disposed.

Other than that i believe it should be safe for you as long as you respect the boundaries of your context. I.E does not run operations in paralell on different thread in the request, which uses this context instance for example.